# How do I pass parameters in Javascript + Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function below where I want to pass a parameter into the runQuery method like runQuery(90) to select any desired row count. But because of err and connection I do not know where to place it. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
var runQuery = oracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection, par1) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error connecting to db:", err);
        return;
    }

    connection.execute("SELECT * FROM HR where rownum <" + par1, [], function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error executing query:", err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(results);
        connection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle), you could try refactor your function as follows (untested):

```
function runQuery(stmt, row_num, cb) {
    stmt.execute([row_num], function(err, count) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        if (count !== 1) return cb(new Error("bad count: " + count));
        // We are done
        return cb();
    });
}

var statement = connection.prepare("SELECT * FROM HR where rownum < :1");
runQuery(statement, 90, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error executing query:", err);
        return;
    }

    console.log(results);
    connection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing 
});
```

The prepared statement contains the parameter you wish to pass in your select statement. This of course hasn't been tested but hopefully will give you good pointers towards what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first stab at Javascript, coming from a VB world it really is a learning curve but I have been doing bash scripts that is why I figure I will give a try at js. Thanks again!

Comment: To make your answer even better it would be good to point out explicitly the security hole in the OP's code, and what the OP was doing wrong. (I did the latter but I was working on the former when you wrote your answer and I decided to just quit.)

Comment: Great pointers Louis, will factor in the advice. Had to study the documentation to see if there are better ways of passing in parameters to statements and found the example for bulk inserts/updates.